# Can I carry over my points over the rep cap?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Suppose I have hit the daily reputation cap and my upvote gets cut-off. Can I just forward the points I lost to the next day? Otherwise it seems like the answerer loses out.

Comment: It's Stack Overflow's way of telling you to do something else! Don't forget votes received after the rep cap is hit still count towards the "Nice Answer", "Good Answer" badges and also the tag badges.

Comment: First time I've heard of at least 200 rep in a day described as "losing out."  I have visited SO on 328 days, and have only hit the rep cap on 18; would be happy to "lose out" more often! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If it were, then there wouldn't really be a cap at all. And since the cap serves a useful purpose, we should keep things the way they are.

You *could* come up with good answers to questions and not post them until the next day, but there are (at least) two problems with that:

- someone else might post an equally good or better answer first
- it's pretty selfish to withhold information just to try to increase what is only a marginally meaningful number in the first place

Comment: +1 mostly for the second point. Reputation is a fun side-game; it should never be the main reason for participation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I agree .

Comment: just wanted to know ruels

Answer (score 3):

I disagree, that would defeat the point of the rep cap unless you hit it every day. Currently, the rep cap encourages participation over time and prevents you getting a lot of rep for one question/answer. However:

- You still earn rep from bounties and accepted answers after you hit the cap.
- You still get badges such as **Nice Answer** (as ChrisF said).