# Accepted answers don't obey rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I know that accepted answers aren't included in the daily reputation cap, but does this apply retroactively?

Say I hit the cap day 1, but got 32 upvotes (320 => limit 200). The next day I get 10 upvotes (100 => 100), two weeks later it gets the accepted answer. Does this require a recalc or do I automatically get the 120 reputation from the first day?

Comment: I don't understand what the upvotes have to do with the accepted answer?

Comment: Technically those 12 votes get ignored on the first day, I'm saying are those applied retroactively or not once the answer is accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Technically those 12 votes get ignored on the first day, I'm saying are those applied retroactively or not once the answer is accepted.

And they're still ignored later.  Once you hit the rep cap for a day, you won't get more rep for votes cast on that day.

If upvotes were "saved up" to be applied later, there *wouldn't be* a rep cap, it would just be delayed gain.

---

I now see the problem is you're misinterpreting:

> ...you can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit).

That should be [clarified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68136/54262) to say something along the lines of "although the bonuses for getting an answer accepted or earning a bounty are immune to this limit".  It's the +15 rep that doesn't count towards the cap, not the votes on the accepted answer.

It's parsed as:

> (accepted answers and bounty) awards
>   (accepted answer awards) and (bounty awards)

Rather than "(accepted answers) and (bounty awards)".  Note the change from "answers" to "answer" which could make it harder to understand if you don't know a priori.

Comment: *"you can earn a maximum of  200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit"*. Even for accepted answers?

Comment: @Roger: Got it. Sometimes I re-read the FAQ's and wonder if they are written by very smart people or if I'm just very dumb.

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/can-i-carry-over-my-points-over-the-rep-cap/65549#65549).

Comment: @Josh: Clear, unambiguous, technical writing is hard to do without being boring.

Comment: @Roger Pate: maybe it would be easier to understand in a logical language, say [Lojban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban) :p