# Clarify FAQ on reputation cap

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request, site-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarification about daily cap and accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62973/clarification-about-daily-cap-and-accepted-answers)

> ...you can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit).

This can be [interpreted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68129/54262) to mean *upvotes on accepted answers* aren't capped.  Instead, it should say something similar to:

> (although the bonuses for getting an answer accepted or earning a bounty are immune to this limit)

Or perhaps:

> (although accepted answer rewards and bounty awards are immune to this limit)

Comment: @Roger, argh, you noticed my comment before I caught my mistake. I meant that I would go edit the FAQ. Then I realized you meant `sitename.com/faq`, not the community-edited FAQ of questions tagged `[faq]`.

Comment: @Popular: Ah, yeah.  I couldn't recall a tag dedicated to the site FAQ, but I've already used [site-faq] on a different meta.  Do you happen to know if there is one?  (Could've prevented that confusion? ;)

Comment: @Roger, I'm at a loss, sorry.

Comment: The trouble is, this is more complicated to express, since the immunity only applies _after_ reaching 200 rep. If you gain 200 rep from upvotes _and_ accepted answers/bounties and _then_ get upvotes, they are capped despite part of your 200 rep are caused by acceptance/awarding

Comment: @Tobias: That's no longer true.  Looking at my [rep-audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation), I had a day not long ago where I got two acceptances at <200 rep, then when upvotes got capped, I finished the day at 230.

Comment: See http://codepad.org/zj1rNWjC (this is a short-lived paste and I'll delete this comment in a week or so)

Comment: @Roger Pate: in that case its fine. and less confusing too :)