# Can we change the wording on the FAQ regarding the exception to the daily rate cap related to accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request, site-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarify FAQ on reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68136/clarify-faq-on-reputation-cap)
>   [Daily reputation limit and accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139962/daily-reputation-limit-and-accepted-answers)

Currently the FAQ says,

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

The bit about accepted answers is worded poorly and has [caused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62973/158779) [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68136/158779) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68129/158779).  Some people very reasonably think that having an answer accepted moves it into a special status where upvotes for that question are not subject to daily rep cap.

I propose something like the following instead:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answer awards and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: Word repetition, uck. If you just remove the "s" from "answers" then it reads like the "awards" applies to both "accepted answer and bounty". Reverse pluralization bug!

Comment: This isn't a pluralization bug...the wording changes the meaning.  As worded, **I** believe it is **wrong**, but it is at least very ambiguous.

Comment: The duplicate should have a better title indicating that it is about changing the wording in the FAQ, but the question definitely addresses the same issue you do.

Comment: This could also be considered a duplicate of either of the first two "caused confusion before" posts.

Comment: @PopularDemand OK, but I just want someone to take 30 seconds and fix this.  How do I make that happen?  More time was spent looking for duplicates than it would take to fix this issue once and for all.

Comment: Reading my last comment again, I can see how it could look a little pointed. I was only trying to make the point for future visitors that this is an issue with some weight behind it. It wasn't intended as criticism directed at you, I apologize if it came across that way. As for getting someone to make the fix... I don't know what to tell you. It's not like the team has been unable to change that text since the first time this was brought up.

Comment: @PopularDemand No hard feelings :) I'm just a bit frustrated because, although I know developer time is finite and I'm sure other things are more important than this, it can literally be fixed in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than your suggestion, I propose the following slight variation (which is fairly inline with [my previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139964/165455)):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from up-votes. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while reputation earned specifically from the acceptance of an answer (+15 or +2), reputation from bounty awards, and reputation from the association bonus*, are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

It might even help to append an illustrative example:

> For example, if yesterday you received 25 answer up-votes, had three answers accepted, and accepted an answer to one of your questions, your total reputation for the day would be 247 (+200 max for up-votes, +45 (3*15) for accepted answers, and +2 for accepting an answer).

[*] [this just came up here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147411/should-the-association-bonus-count-toward-200-points-in-one-day).

Comment: This works also.  I just want someone with the right powers to take the 30 seconds and change the wording so there is no confusion, as it has been mentioned several times that currently it **is** a source of confusion.

Comment: You can actually get more than 200 a day from upvotes, if there are also some downvotes involved (received or payed for). This is difficult to get exactly correct!

Comment: @Bo well, isn't the SUM of that activity never > 200? For example, if I'm at 200, then get a down-vote, I'm at 198. If I get another up-vote, it only counts for 2, not 10. If I get another up-vote nothing counts. Timing is important at the end of the day, which has always bugged my anal retentive side - if I'm at 200 and get a down-vote at 11:58 and an up-vote at 11:59, I'm still at 200 when the day ends. If I'm at 200 and get an up-vote at 11:58 and a down-vote at 11:59, I'm at 198 for the day.

Comment: @Aaron - Yes, the net of the votes is limited to 200 a day, not the upvotes alone. And the order is important too, I have ended up at 199 after finding an answer I didn't like. :-)