# Should the Association Bonus count toward 200 points in one day?

Tags: support, association, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

On Stack Overflow, I crossed the 200-point mark on my total reputation points on the same day that I earned 155 points by answering questions and collecting a bounty.  My total points for the day, then were 255.  I had thought that would've given me a [Mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/144/mortarboard) (Earn at least 200 points in a single day), but I didn't get it.  Does the 100-point Association Bonus not count toward your total for the day?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I assumed that was the case.

Comment: Thanks for the link(s) Bart.  I didn't find that initially, but it was very enlightening

Comment: I think the number of people who get 200 points on their first day on a site is extremely small.