# Hitting the Daily Reputation Cap

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I carry over my points over the rep cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/can-i-carry-over-my-points-over-the-rep-cap)

If i hit it, where do the points go, do they get carried over to the next day or are they gone forever?

Comment: This might be better asked over on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: whoops, have never even clicked on Meta!

Answer (score 2):

Lost in the wilderness of time.

Comment: Doomed to wander the plane of ghosts and wind for eternity...

Comment: like tears in the rain

Comment: like farts in the wind.